# scrollView not scrolling all my contents

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

I'm using a scrollView and inside it used a view.

[image]

I set sizes like this:

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

I think the height of my view always is 959.
but when I change the height from 959 to 2000, I see a orange line and when I use `Editor->resolve Auto..->update frames` my custom hight returns to 959.

even when I set height from pin I see red lines:

[image]

[image]

I want all my content scrolling. The  content's height is 2000.

Comment: The problem exactly is that scrollView is not able to identify the content because of improper constraints. Give bottom to the last view in the screen  or top constraints of top most view in the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You check this following way:

**Scrollview** Constraints:

Set **top** to your **super view**

Set **bottom** to your **super view**

Set **leading** to your **super view**

Set **trailling** to your **super view**

Take One **UIView** into scrollview and apply following constraints(Equal to same **Scrollview** **width** and **Height**)

Set **top** to scrollview

Set **bottom** to scrollview

Set **leading** to scrollview

Set **trailling** to scrollview

Dont forget to set **Equal width** to scrollview

Then do add your all UIElements whatever you want.
Consider like below:

lable 1----> set necessory constraint to UIView

lable 2----> set necessory constraint to UIView

lable 3----> set necessory constraint to UIView

lable 4----> set necessory constraint to UIView

lable 5----> set necessory constraint to UIView and you give **Bottom** constraint to UIView

Then scroll will automatically work..Dont adjust value like that.If you want more large screen Change **View controller** Simulated size to **Freeform** and there you adjust your prefer height and place scrollview based on that.