# iOS Autolayout scrollview scrolls horizontally

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, autolayout

I am implementing an example from Pluralsight where I have a `scrollview` and a few `buttons` centered horizontally. I have leading and trailing constraints of `50` for each `button`. When I change the trailing to `51`, I also scrolls horizontally. Why is this happening? No `button` width is forcing the button out of the screen's width.I guess it has something to do with how `autolayout` works. [image]

Comment: remove button width if you added

Comment: No width is specified

Comment: best option to work with Autolayout & scrollview is that add a UIView on your scrollview & now add your buttons on added UIView. Life make easier

Comment: add content view in scrollview, then pin your content view lead,trail,bottom,top and equal width to scrollview

see more here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26742230/uiscrollview-in-storyboard-not-working-with-ios-8-size-classes-and-autolayout

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42712113/scrollview-not-scrolling-all-my-contents/42712605#42712605